# Saving and updating event data with a Livewire modal in Laravel 9 FullCalendar project

Tags: html, jquery, fullcalendar, laravel-livewire, fullcalendar-5

I've managed to construct a Laravel 9 project with FullCalendar 5 as a Livewire component. I have a single modal constructed that gets fired when an open date on the calendar is clicked (firing the 'select' function) and when an existing event is clicked (firing the eventClick function). The eventClick function populates the event data from the database within the input fields on the modal.

I need help getting the "save" button on both the updateEvent and addEvent functions within the modal to create or edit information in the database respectively.

here's the fullCalendar view in blade format in its entirety:

```
<style>
  #calendar-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #events {
        grid-column: 1;
    }
    #calendar {
        grid-column: 2;
        height: 700px;
    }
    .dropEvent {
        background-color: DodgerBlue;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 16px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
<div>
  @include('livewire.eventmodal')
<div>
  <!-- sidebar -->
    <div id="calendar-container" wire:ignore>
        <div id="events">
            <div data-event='{"title":"Evénement A"}' class="dropEvent">Event One Drag</div>
            <div data-event='{"title":"Evénement B"}' class="dropEvent">Event Two Draggable</div>
        </div>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

@push('scripts')
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.10.1/main.min.js'></script>
<script>
create_UUID = () => {
let dt = new Date().getTime();
const uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
    let r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r :(r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
});
return uuid;
}
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
const Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
const Draggable = FullCalendar.Draggable;
    new Draggable(document.getElementById('events'), {
        itemSelector: '.dropEvent'
    });
const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  headerToolbar: {
        left: 'promptResource prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceMonth,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
      },
      views: {
        resourceMonth: {
        type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
        buttonText: 'personnel'
        }
      },
      customButtons: {
        promptResource: {
          text: "+ personnel",
      click: function() {
        var title = prompt("Name");
        if (title) {
          calendar.addResource({
            title: title
          });
          fetch("add_resources.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json"
            },
            body: encodeFormData({ title: title })
          })
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
      }
    }
  },
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    locale: '{{ config('app.locale') }}',
    events: JSON.parse(@this.events),
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Personnel',
    resources: JSON.parse(@this.resources),
    //'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    editable: true,
    eventResize: info => @this.eventChange(info.event),
    eventDrop: info => @this.eventChange(info.event),
    eventReceive: info => {
        const id = create_UUID();
          info.event.setProp('id', id);
          @this.eventAdd(info.event);
    },
    selectable: true,
    select: function(info) {
          $('#eventModal').modal('show');
          },

    eventClick: function(info, event) {
          // Display the modal and set the values to the event values.
          $('#updateEventModal').modal('show');
          $('#updateEventModal').find('#title').val(info.event.title);
          $('#updateEventModal').find('#acronym').val(info.event.extendedProps.acronym);
          $('#updateEventModal').find('#city').val(info.event.extendedProps.city);
          $('#updateEventModal').find('#venue').val(info.event.extendedProps.venue);
          $('#updateEventModal').find('#value').val(info.event.extendedProps.value);
          $('#updateEventModal').find('#start').val(info.event.start);
          $('#updateEventModal').find('#end').val(info.event.end);
          $('#calendar').calendar ('updateEvent', event);
          },
});
calendar.render();
});
</script>
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
@endpush
```

Here's the calendar component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Resource;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

class Calendar extends Component
{
    public $events, $resources, $title, $acronym, $city, $venue, $value ;


    public function eventChange ( $event )
    {
    $e=Event::find($event['id']) ;
    $e->start=$event['start'] ;
    if(Arr::exists($event,'end')) {
        $e->end=$event['end'];
    }
    $e->save();
    }

    public function saveEvent()
        {
            $validatedData = $this->validate();

            Event::create($validatedData);
            session()->flash('message','Event Added Successfully');
            $this->resetInput();
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal');
        }


    public function render()
    {
        $this->events=json_encode(Event::all());
        $this->resources=json_encode(Resource::all());
        return view('livewire.calendar');
    }
    public function eventAdd ( $event )
    {
      Event::create ( $event );
    }
    public function eventRemove ( $id )
    {
      Event::destroy ( $id );
    }
    public function resourceAdd ( $resources )
    {
      Resource::create ( $resources );
    }
    public function resourceRemove ( $id )
    {
      Resource::destroy ( $id );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't run `$('#calendar').calendar ('updateEvent', event)` inside the `eventClick` function. That will run before the user has had time to update anything in the modal. Does your modal have a form with a "save" button (or similar)? You need to handle the submit event of that form (or click event of the button, if you prefer), suppress its default postback behaviour, and then run your AJAX call to send data to the server to update the event. And you can of course also try to update the event in the front-end calendar too at the same time.

Comment: `$('#calendar').calendar ('updateEvent', event);` is not the right syntax though, in any case. That's syntax from fullCalendar 3. There are a lot of examples online for that older version. After v4 it stopped being a jQuery plugin, and the syntax for it changed entirely. When you're finding examples on the web, always make sure they apply to the version of fullCalendar you're using. You can of course always check the [fullcalendar documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc) to verify this.

Comment: In v5 there is no single "update" method (don't ask me why, I didn't design it!). Instead you'll need to modify each relevant property of the event separately - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-model .

Comment: Or, if you were to use a dynamic [event feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) for `events:` rather than a static ready-made list of events, you could skip updating the event in the front-end and instead, when your AJAX updating call finishes, you could call [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-refetchEvents) which would automatically update the event data from the server for you. That won't work with a static list though obviously, as there's no source URL that fullCalendar knows about to fetch new data from.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build and AddEvent modal and an EditEvent modal within the livewire component.

Here's my blade view:

```
<style>
  #calendar-container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 200px 1fr;
        padding: 20px;
    }
    #events {
        grid-column: 1;
    }
    #calendar {
        grid-column: 2;
        height: 700px;
    }
    .dropEvent {
        background-color: DodgerBlue;
        color: white;
        padding: 5px 16px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        cursor:pointer;
    }
</style>
<div>
  @include('livewire.eventmodal')
<div>
  <!-- sidebar -->
    <div id="calendar-container" wire:ignore>
        <div id="events">
            <div data-event='{"title":"Evénement A"}' class="dropEvent">Event One Drag</div>
            <div data-event='{"title":"Evénement B"}' class="dropEvent">Event Two Draggable</div>
        </div>
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- start add event modal -->
<div id="AddEventModal" class="modal fade">
  <form action="/events" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4>Add Event</h4> &nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
            </div>
            <!-- <form wire:submit.prevent="saveEvent"> -->
            <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
              <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <label for="title" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Title</label>
                  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                         value="{{ old('title', '') }}" />
                  @error('title')
                      <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <label for="acronym" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Acronym</label>
                  <input type="text" name="acronym" id="acronym" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                         value="{{ old('acronym', '') }}" />
                  @error('acronym')
                      <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <label for="city" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">City</label>
                  <input type="text" name="city" id="city" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                         value="{{ old('city', '') }}" />
                  @error('city')
                      <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <label for="venue" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Venue</label>
                  <input type="text" name="venue" id="venue" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                         value="{{ old('venue', '') }}" />
                  @error('venue')
                      <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <label for="value" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Value</label>
                  <input type="text" name="value" id="value" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                         value="{{ old('value', '') }}" />
                  @error('value')
                      <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <label for="start" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Start Date</label>
                  <input type="text" name="start" id="start" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                         value="{{ old('start', '') }}" />
                  @error('start')
                      <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                  @enderror
              </div>
              <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <label for="end" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">End Date</label>
                  <input type="text" name="end" id="end" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                         value="{{ old('end', '') }}" />
                  @error('end')
                      <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                  @enderror
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#AddEventModal" id="submit">Save</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--end add event modal -->

<!--start edit event modal -->
  <div id="EditEventModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <form action="/events" method="POST">
      {{csrf_field()}}
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h4>Add Event</h4> &nbsp;
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span> <span class="sr-only">close</span></button>
              </div>
              <!-- <form wire:submit.prevent="saveEvent"> -->
              <div id="modalBody" class="modal-body">
                <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <label for="title" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                           value="{{ old('title', '') }}" />
                    @error('title')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <label for="acronym" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Acronym</label>
                    <input type="text" name="acronym" id="acronym" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                           value="{{ old('acronym', '') }}" />
                    @error('acronym')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <label for="city" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                           value="{{ old('city', '') }}" />
                    @error('city')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <label for="venue" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Venue</label>
                    <input type="text" name="venue" id="venue" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                           value="{{ old('venue', '') }}" />
                    @error('venue')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <label for="value" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Value</label>
                    <input type="text" name="value" id="value" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                           value="{{ old('value', '') }}" />
                    @error('value')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <label for="start" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">Start Date</label>
                    <input type="text" name="start" id="start" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                           value="{{ old('start', '') }}" />
                    @error('start')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div class="bg-white sm:p-6">
                    <label for="end" class="block font-medium text-sm text-gray-700">End Date</label>
                    <input type="text" name="end" id="end" type="text" class="form-input rounded-md shadow-sm mt-1 block w-full"
                           value="{{ old('end', '') }}" />
                    @error('end')
                        <p class="text-sm text-red-600">{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditEventModal" id="updateBtn">Save</button>
              </div>
            </form>
      </div>
  </div>

</div>

@push('scripts')
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.27.0/min/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/moment@5.11.3/main.global.min.js'></script>
<script>
create_UUID = () => {
let dt = new Date().getTime();
const uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, c => {
    let r = (dt + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    dt = Math.floor(dt / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r :(r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
});
return uuid;
}
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
const Calendar = FullCalendar.Calendar;
const calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
const Draggable = FullCalendar.Draggable;
    new Draggable(document.getElementById('events'), {
        itemSelector: '.dropEvent'
    });
const calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  titleFormat: function(date) {
    return date.toString() + '!!!';
  },
  headerToolbar: {
        left: 'promptResource prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceMonth,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
      },
      views: {
        resourceMonth: {
        type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
        buttonText: 'personnel'
        }
      },
      customButtons: {
        promptResource: {
          text: "+ personnel",
      click: function() {
        var title = prompt("Name");
        if (title) {
          calendar.addResource({
            title: title
          });
          fetch("add_resources.php", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json"
            },
            body: encodeFormData({ title: title })
          })
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
      }
    }
  },
    initialView: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
    locale: '{{ config('app.locale') }}',
    events: JSON.parse(@this.events),
    resourceAreaHeaderContent: 'Personnel',
    resources: JSON.parse(@this.resources),
    //'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/resources.json?with-nesting&with-colors',
    editable: true,
    //eventLimit: true,
    eventResize: info => @this.eventChange(info.event),
    eventDrop: info => @this.eventChange(info.event),
    eventReceive: info => {
        const id = create_UUID();
          info.event.setProp('id', id);
          @this.eventAdd(info.event);
    },
    selectable: true,
    
      select: function(selectionInfo) {
        $('#AddEventModal').find('#start').val(selectionInfo.start);
        $('#AddEventModal').find('#end').val(selectionInfo.end);
        //alert('selected ' + info.startStr + ' to ' + info.endStr);
        $('#AddEventModal').modal('show');

    $('#saveBtn').click(function() {
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var start = moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        var end = moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('event.store') }}",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data:{ title, acronym, city, venue, value, start, end, color  },
            success:function(response)
            {
                $('#AddEventModal').modal('hide')
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                    'title': response.title,
                    'acronym': response.acronym,
                    'city': response.city,
                    'venue': response.venue,
                    'value': response.value,
                    'start' : response.start,
                    'end'  : response.end,
                    'color' : response.color
                });

            },
            error:function(error)
            {
                if(error.responseJSON.errors) {
                    $('#titleError').html(error.responseJSON.errors.title);
                }
            },
        });
    });
  },
        

    eventClick: function(info) {
                  //  var start = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                  //  var end = moment(event.end).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                  $('#EditEventModal').modal('show');
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#id').val(info.event.id);
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#title').val(info.event.title);
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#acronym').val(info.event.extendedProps.acronym);
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#city').val(info.event.extendedProps.city);
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#venue').val(info.event.extendedProps.venue);
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#value').val(info.event.extendedProps.value);
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#start').val(info.event.start);
                  $('#EditEventModal').find('#end').val(info.event.end);
                  $('#EditEventModal').modal('show');

                    $.ajax({
                            url:"{{ route('calendar.update', '') }}" +'/'+ id,
                            type:"PATCH",
                            dataType:'json',
                            data:{ start, end  },
                            success:function(response)
                            {
                                swal("Good job!", "Event Updated!", "success");
                            },
                            error:function(error)
                            {
                                console.log(error)
                            },
                        });
                },

});
calendar.render();


            $("#AddEventModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
                $('#saveBtn').unbind();
            });

            $("#EditEventModal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
                $('#updateBtn').unbind();
            });

            $('.fc-event').css('font-size', '13px');
            $('.fc-event').css('width', '20px');
            $('.fc-event').css('border-radius', '50%');


});
</script>
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.11.3/main.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
@endpush
```

Here's my EVENT controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\StoreEventRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateEventRequest;
use App\Models\Event;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('event_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $events = Event::all();

        return view('events.index', compact('events'));
    }

    public function create()
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('event_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        return view('events.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string'
        ]);

        $event = Event::create([
            'title' => $request->title,
            'acronym' => $request->acronym,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'venue' => $request->venue,
            'value' => $request->value,
            'start' => $request->start,
            'end' => $request->end,
        ]);

        $color = null;

        if($event->title == 'Test') {
            $color = '#924ACE';
        }

        return redirect('/dashboard')-> with('success', 'Event Added'); response()->json([
            'id' => $event->id,
            'title' => $event->title,
            'acronym' => $request->acronym,
            'city' => $request->city,
            'venue' => $request->venue,
            'value' => $request->value,
            'start' => $event->start,
            'end' => $event->end,
          //  'color' => $color ? $color: '',

        ]);
    }


    public function show(Event $event)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('event_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        return view('events.show', compact('event'));
    }

    public function edit(Event $event)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('event_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        return view('events.edit', compact('event'));
    }


    public function update(Request $request ,$id)
{
    $event = Event::find($id);
    if(! $event) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Unable to locate the event'
        ], 404);
    }
    $event->update([
        'start' => $request->start,
        'end' => $request->end,
    ]);
    return response()->json('Event updated');
}

    public function destroy(Event $event)
    {
        abort_if(Gate::denies('event_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

        $event->delete();

        return redirect()->route('events.index');
    }
}
```

And here are the associated routes:

```
Route::get('calendar/index', [CalendarController::class, 'index'])->name('calendar.index');
Route::post('calendar', [EventController::class, 'store'])->name('event.store');
Route::patch('calendar/update/{id}', [CalendarController::class, 'update'])->name('calendar.update');
Route::delete('calendar/destroy/{id}', [CalendarController::class, 'destroy'])->name('calendar.destroy');
```

This isn't an ideal solution because of the following issues:

1. The save action on the add event isn't using Livewire, rather ajax and jquery. I'd like to stick with Livewire purely.
2. When you select an event on the calendar by clicking on a date or a date range, the select method doesn't pick up the actual date arguments from the calendar.
3. The submit function on the edit modal DUPLICATES the event rather than editing the existing event.